# Iterate over object properties and change them?

Tags: python, properties

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do here:

```
for item in [self.docket_numbers, self.neutral_citations,
             self.lower_courts, self.lower_court_judges,
             self.dispositions, self.judges, self.nature_of_suit]:
    if item is not None:
        item = [clean_string(sub_item) for sub_item in item]
```

Obviously, in the last line, I need to assign the result of the list interpretation back to the object...but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the various items are lists, which it kind of looks like they are, you don't need setattr, you can simply change them in-place:

```
>>> def clean_string(s):
...     return ''.join(c for c in s if c != '7')
... 
>>> class Court(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.docket_numbers = ["a1", "b277"]
...         self.dispositions = ["happy", "sad77"]
...     def clean(self):
...         for item in [self.docket_numbers, self.dispositions]:
...             if item is not None:
...                 item[:] = [clean_string(sub_item) for sub_item in item]
... 
>>> C = Court()
>>> vars(C)
{'dispositions': ['happy', 'sad77'], 'docket_numbers': ['a1', 'b277']}
>>> C.clean()
>>> vars(C)
{'dispositions': ['happy', 'sad'], 'docket_numbers': ['a1', 'b2']}
```

Comment: I love SO sometimes. Thanks for the quick, detailed, and fantastic answer that worked just by my adding [:] to my current code. Can you explain what that does? I've never seen it  before?

Comment: The `[:]` indicates a slice with no start or end specified, which means that it takes the whole thing. `a_list[:]` makes a shallow copy of the list. When assigning to that slice, it means that you remove the specified slice and replace it with the given list, so `a_list[:] = b_list` will give `a_list` all the contents of `b_list`, while still maintaining the object identity of `a_list` (that's why you don't need `setattr` that way).

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over the names; then you can use `getattr` and `setattr`.

```
for attr in ('docket_numbers', 'neutral_citations',
             'lower_courts', 'lower_court_judges',
             'dispositions', 'judges', 'nature_of_suit'):
    item = getattr(self, attr)
    if item is not None:
        setattr(self, attr, [clean_string(sub_item) for sub_item in item])
```

Comment: A little more complicated than DSM's answer, but thank you anyway. Educational.

Comment: @mlissner This is the more general solution as it doesn't depend on the items being lists.